# Como esconder elemento button usando apenas CSS?

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando utilizar a propriedade `display: none` no elemento `button`, mas não funciona. Se coloco na classe ele funciona, p.ex:

```
.btn {
     display: none;
     }
```

Mas se coloco no elemento `button` não funciona:

```
button {
     display: none;
     }
```

Então a pergunta é como faço para esconder os elementos `button` sem precisar usar classe?

Comment: É claro que funciona... https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/be5mcp28/ podes criar um exemplo do teu problema?

Comment: kkkk eita, devo ter feito algo errado aqui! vou conferir, valeu Sérgio!

Comment: Sérgio, estava com conflito mesmo, por isso não funcionava, com o `!important` sugerido na resposta abaixo funcionou...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É provável que o seu css esteja em conflito com algum outro, neste caso você pode aumentar o peso do css. Por exemplo:

```
div #btnEnviar.btn {
     display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Ah, era isso mesmo, não sei se por estar usando o bootstrap, ou se pode ter algo a ver com o js, mas com o `!important` funcionou... valeu, daqui a pouco confirmo a resposta (quando passar o tempo mínimo)...

Comment: @gustavox é o Bootstrap sim ! kkk tive esse problema inúmeras vezes.